# Creating geomap with python

Tags: python, seaborn, geopandas

I have the following dataset as CSV

```
country,  country_code,  score
England,  en,            5.1
Ukrain,   uk,            9.2
Italy,    it,            3.1
...       ...            ...
```

I try to use the following code to create a geomap based on the score column in my dataset.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")]
world.head() 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
world.plot(column='pop_est', ax=ax, legend=True)
```

This code uses a demo data. But I have to apply it to my dataset. I tried to use read_csv method but geopandas doesn't have this method. How can I import my data from CSV in that case?

Comment: Use `pandas`, it has .`read_csv()`.